# error CS0117 in Unity

Tags: c#, cursor, unityscript

I am working in Unity 5.1 as a beginner,
Now i got an error and i've no idea how to solve this:

```
Assets/SampleAssets/Cameras/Scripts/FreeLookCam.cs(39,32): error CS0117: `UnityEngine.Screen' does not contain a definition for `Cursor'
```

my script is:

```
   private void OnDisable()
    {
        Screen.Cursor.lockState = Cursor.visible;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? What's the content of FreeLookCam.cs?

Comment: too much characters in the script to post...

Answer (score 0):

Just remove Screen. so the code becomes:

```
private void OnDisable(){
  Curser.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}
```

however, if you want to hide/display the cursor use this:

```
Cursor.visible = true;
Cursor.visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cursor class resides in `UnityEngine` instead of `Screen` class. So it is unable to find `Cursor.lockState`. Have a look at [this example of doc](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor-lockState.html) on how it should be use.